# Predicate in C# .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, predicate

I am still a beginner on .NET and .NET Core. I am not sure how the syntax of predicate works in .NET CORE.

```
  [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<TodoItem>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        var items = await DocumentDBRepository<TodoItem>.GetItemsAsync(t => t.IsComplete);
        return items;
    }
```

The GetItemsAsync() from above code **has red underline in the .NET Core framework but not the .NET framework.**

The signature of the GetItemAsync() is:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
```

The error message is

```
> "The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
> "DocumentDBRepository<T>.GetItemsAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>>)" and
> "DocumentDBRepository<T>.GetItemsAsync(Func<TodoItem, body>)"
```

Could someone explain why?

Comment: What is the error that you're getting if you try to build this?

Comment: @zaitsman just added

Comment: There must be another `GetItemsAsync(Func<T, bool>` defined.

Comment: @NetMage ahh my bad. Thanks!!

Comment: If you already know the answer, post and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another GetItemsAsync(Func) in the class. Both functions have different parameters. It worked after I commented this function GetItemsAsync(Func).

Thanks @NetMage